# PHP not looping as I would like

Tags: php

From the code below, this what I'm trying to achieve: If citizenID found by the $get_friends query are 1 and 2. I would like the while loop to first get all the rows for 1 and then do the same for 2. The code I currently have below its only retrieving the last row for 1 and 2. Please help.

```
<?php

include ('session_start.php');
include_once('db_connect_universal.php');

$user_id = $_SESSION['sess_id'];

//GET USER FRIENDS AND DETAILS
$get_friends = "SELECT * FROM citizens
                INNER JOIN user_details 
                ON citizens.citizenID=user_details.UserID 
                WHERE citizens.userID = '".$user_id."'";

$results_get_friends = $conn->query($get_friends);

$num_rows_friends = mysqli_num_rows ($results_get_friends);

while ($row_friends = $results_get_friends->fetch_assoc()) {

    $citizenID = $row_friends['citizenID'];

    //GET RATINGS AND COMMENTS
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments
                INNER JOIN organiser ON comments.movieID=organiser.movieID 
            WHERE comments.userID= '".$citizenID."'  
              AND ratings_n_comments.Time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY) 
                                              AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
            ORDER BY comments.Time DESC";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

    $n_Rating[]= array(
                        'dp' => $row_friends['display_pics'],
                        'uname' => $row_friends['Uname'],
                        'poster'=> $row['mooster'],
                        'title'=> $row['moitle'],
                        'genre'=> $row['moenre'],
                        'comment'=> $row['Comment'],
                        'mid'=> $row['mID'],
                        'check' => 'data'
                    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode ($n_Rating);

}

//detailed error reporting
if (!$sql) {
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sensible code indentation makes debugging code much easier for you

Comment: `if (!$sql) {` ?? `$sql` is a string literal containing a query. NOT a result from issuing a query. So your error reporting apart from being way too late in the process wont ever give you any help like reporting errors

Comment: You seem to have an unnecessary `}`

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly thanks for your suggestions, however can you please help me with my main issue?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Thanks RiggyFolly, but this isn't my main issue :(

Comment: If you add that code and run your script, you will see any MYSQLI errors, That woudl be a good start. If there are none, then we can try and continue

Comment: There are no errors, the script is outputting what has been coded, I just don't know how to code what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only fetching one row with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`.

Are you trying to fetch all the comments for the users?

Because then you'll need to loop trough everything `$result` has just like you are doing with `while ($row_friends = $results_get_friends->fetch_assoc())`

Also instead of concatenating your SQL query, try using [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to [avoid possible SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Silly me, all good now, thank you so much jkrnak. Also thanks for your suggestions on using prepare and bind_param, will look into it.